# VIX API Locale for non-Unicode programs Error

Tags: sdk, vmware, vmware-workstation, vix

I use the VIX API 1.11 on the Windows OS and I have a problem with locale for non-Unicode programs.

When I try to call the VixHost_Connect() function to connect to VmWare Workstation Hypervisor, I have the error window on the screen with the message:

"File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\VmWare\preferences.ini" line 2:

Value "VmWare Workstation" for variable "pref.eula.0.appName" is not valid in encoding "windows-1252".
Unable to read user preferences (file in attached)

Does anybody know the solution?

--

Kind Regards,
Alex Kolesnyk

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have been faced the same problem, but I fixed it somehow.
I just have opened the "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\VmWare\preferences.ini" in notepad,
and changed the first line like below and the warning has been gone.

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
```

->

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
```